# Direct sum of column space and null space of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. Let $C(A)$ and $N(A)$ denote the column and null space of $A$, respectively, and let $\oplus$ denote the direct sum operator.

> Prove: $C(A) \oplus N(A) = \mathbb R^n$

Firstly, is this even true? If so, how does one prove this? It's clear that $\text{dim}(C(A)) = r$ (the rank) and $\text{dim}(N(A)) = n-r$, but how do we show that $C(A) \cap N(A) = \{0\}$?

Comment: Let $R(A)$ be the row space of $A$, then $R(A)\oplus N(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes , but $R(A) \neq C(A)$ for a square matrix, in general.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then consider $A=\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 }$.

Comment: The argument is purely about dimension.  Consider $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  The column space is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, and so is the null space.  The direct sum treats the two duplicated vectors as different vectors.